# Nivo-Slider plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

The plugin doesnt seem to be working for me on this project im working on, whenever i load the page to view the slider the transitions aren't working, i've looked at the file paths for the references to the javascript files and css files and they are correct.

I'll post the code below if anyone could help that'd be great!

Jquery:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'boxRain', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: 15, // For slice animations
        boxCols: 8, // For box animations
        boxRows: 4, // For box animations
        animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: false, // Next & Prev navigation
        controlNav: false, // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
        prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
        randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
        beforeChange: function () { }, // Triggers before a slide transition
        afterChange: function () { }, // Triggers after a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function () { }, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function () { }, // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function () { } // Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
});
```

File Refs:

```
<script src="assets/Nivo-Slider-master/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/Nivo-Slider-master/nivoslider.jquery.json"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/Nivo-Slider-master/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Example Slider code of mine:

```
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider" >
       <uc1:ImageCarouselll runat="server" ID="ctrl_Images" />
    </div>

    <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" style="display: none;">
         <div class="slides" style="width: 138240px;"></div>
         <h3 class="title">Image from Unsplash</h3>
         <a class="prev">‹</a>
         <a class="next">›</a>
         <a class="close">×</a>
         <a class="play-pause"></a>
         <ol class="indicator"></ol>
     </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The control code is as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPhotos" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="/images/<%# Eval("ImageURL").ToString() %>" data-gallery="">
            <img class="TheImage" src="/images/<%# Eval("ImageURL").ToString() %>" alt="test" /></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <a href="/images/<%# Eval("ImageURL").ToString() %>" data-gallery="">
            <img class="TheImage" src="/images/<%# Eval("ImageURL").ToString() %>" alt="test" /></a>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: maybe missed to link jQuery?